# How to access a protected method of superclass in a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers

I have parent-child classes in two different packages. I am overriding a method of protected type. I want to access super class protected method in subclass.

Consider below code:

```
package package1;

public class Super
{
    protected void demoMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("In super method");
    }
}

package package2;

import package1.Super;

public class Sub extends Super
{
    @Override
    protected void demoMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("In sub method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //code for accessing superclass demoMethod to print "In super method"
    }
}
```

In the main method of sub class, I want to access super class `demoMethod` which prints "In super method". I know `demoMethod` won't be visible from sub class using super class object reference to call `demoMethod`.

Is it possible or not? If yes, how?

Consider me new to Java and provide answers replacing comment in main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main() method cannot access the superclass implementation of `demoMethod()` -- because it's overridden in the child class.

Your main() method can *access* `demoMethod()`, through a reference of the subclass type, even though it's protected, because it's in the same package as your subclass. But it will call the subclass implementation.

But if you're "using superclass object reference to call demoMethod", the method will not be accessible, and your code will not compile. Your superclass is in a different package. Methods marked `protected` can only be accessed by subclasses and by code in the same package.

If you made the method `public` in both subclass and superclass, calling `demoMethod()` would call the subclass implementation, regardless whether the reference was of the super or subclass type.

An instance of the subclass can call `super.demoMethod()` as part of the implementation of its methods. But the main() method cannot.

Comment: So what am I asking is not possible, right ? Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: yes, as long as the method in this case is `protected` or `public`

Comment: Not with your current access qualifiers and method implementations. If `Super.demoMethod()` were public, you could call it from package2 on an instance of Super, since Super is not declared abstract. But I'm guessing you want to create an object of type Sub. The `main()` method cannot call the superclass implementation, but an instance method of Sub could.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Andy. (y)

Answer (score 2):

In the child class use `super.demoMethod()` or just remove it altogether from the child class

Comment: Neither of these approaches will work if the OP is, as stated, "using superclass object reference to call demoMethod". The superclass method would be inaccessible. Note that it's in a different package.

Comment: Agreed, it would not work from the main method because it is static

Comment: It has nothing to do with main() being static. In this case, *the main() method is in a different package*. It can't access protected members from a different package.

Comment: `protected` allows you access from the same package, or parent classes.

Comment: `protected` allows access within the same package, or by *sub*classes. Neither is the case when using a superclass object reference. This will cause an error: `Super sup = new Sub(); sup.demoMethod()`. More details are in the Java Language Specification in [section 6.6.2: Details on protected access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2): *"A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.*"